# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: , but I am giving the needed argument

Tags: python

edit : Problem solved, I was indeed a idiot and it was indeed a very silly mistake. The solution was that I forgot to give an instance of UI when creating a Joueur instance... Sorry and thanks to all who tried to help me.

I've been trying to code a chess game. I am now in the process of testing it and I got a "weird" error (from my experience I probably just messed up, but my situation is not exactly what people on every other post on this error seem to be and I have been searching my code and documentation for clues for some hours with no success : so here I am).

So to summarize the code (I won't put code I have successfully run before and will only show what should be relevant):

I have a board class which is basically my model and my controller. In the constructor I ask for arguments two players, a UI class, and a hash class. Before I implemented the last two, and added it in the constructor, the code ran just fine.

```
class Plateau:
    def __init__(self, j1, j2, UI, Hash):
        self.UI = UI
        self.UI.ajoutePlateau(self)
        self.Hash = Hash
        self.Hash.hashPlateau(self)
        # some code to deal with the rest
        ...
        #
        self.UI.initAffichage()
```

I then have a UI interface and a ConsolUI (UITerminal in my code) which inherit from it. It is as expected what show to the user the board and also what ask the human player (if there is one) what he wants to play.

```
class UI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Plateau = None

    def ajoutePlateau(self, Plateau):
        self.Plateau = Plateau

    # a bunch of method that throw an exception and are overrided by the child class
        ...
    #
class UITerminal(UI):
    def __init__(self):
        #super(UITerminal, self).__init__(self)
        #super().__init__(self)
        #UI.__init__(self)
        #super(UITerminal, self).__init__()
        super().__init__()
        #UI.__init__()

    # the method that had to be overridden
        ...
    #
```

I have also tried few version of the UITerminal constructor (which are above and put on comment).
or even just nothing since it should not even be needed (I think...).

Then there is the hash, which is build the same way as the UI : an interface, a child.

```
class Hash:
    def __init__(self): 
        pass

    # a bunch of method that throw an exception and are overridden by the child class
        ...
    #

class ZombristHash(Hash):
    def __init__(self):
        #super(ZombristHash, self).__init__(self)
        #super().__init__(self)
        #Hash.__init__(self)
        #super(ZombristHash, self).__init__()
        super().__init__()
        #Hash.__init__()

        # a bunch of code to init the zombristhash
        ...
        #
```

same as with the UI, I tried multiple way to call the interface constructor.

Then I have my main, which is only 1 line and is what throw the error :

```
p = Plateau(Humain("j1"), Humain("j2"), UITerminal(), ZombristHash())
```

and the error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "plateau.py", line 298, in <module> p = Plateau(Humain("j1"), Humain("j2"), UITerminal(), ZombristHash()) 

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'UI'.
```

From what I understand, he tells me I haven't given the board constructor a UI as argument, but I did so I do not understand what is happening.

I tried on quamran's suggestion this :

```
p = Plateau(None, None, None, None)
```

And it seems to think it was ok now...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plateau.py", line 298, in <module>
    p = Plateau(None, None, None, None)
  File "plateau.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.UI.ajoutePlateau(self)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ajoutePlateau'
```

Comment: Please include the actual traceback. Probably this could be much reduced once we see the traceback; please also review the guidance for creating a [mre].

Comment: There is a difference between a class and its *instances*. In your example `UI` is a class object, so `UI.__init__()` doesn't have the required `UI` *instance*. It should be `UI.__init__(self)`.

Comment: @tripleee the complete traceback is just : 
```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plateau.py", line 298, in <module>
    p = Plateau(Humain("j1"), Humain("j2"), UITerminal(), ZombristHash())
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'UI'
```

Comment: Hi @TristanHermant you should have a quick read of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting, there is quite a bit of noise in this question that makes people more inclined to skip over your question.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin I have tried all of the following and it gave me the same error each time.

```
class UITerminal(UI):
 def __init__(self):
  #super(UITerminal, self).__init__(self)
  #super().__init__(self)
  #UI.__init__(self)
  #super(UITerminal, self).__init__()
  #super().__init__()
  UI.__init__()
```

Comment: @TristanHermant: You didn't supply the full traceback. Phoenixo has discovered the problem and has the correct answer.

Comment: @quamrana Sorry for the traceback, it was just two line that I put in my post but should had still put on full anyway. It is now supplied.
And no the solution Phoenixo gave didn't work as I had already tried it, (and did again to confirm) and it still gave me the exact same error.

Comment: Well, can you try :`p = Plateau(None, None, None, None)` to see what the error is?

Comment: @quamrana Now it seems to think it is ok : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plateau.py", line 298, in <module>
    p = Plateau(None, None, None, None)
  File "plateau.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.UI.ajoutePlateau(self)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ajoutePlateau'

Comment: That was the error I was expecting. So, the error in your question is not in `Plateau()`. So now, instead of making Plateau, make one of each of the components: `j2 = Humain("j2"); u = UITerminal(); z = ZombristHash()` and report the error.

Comment: @quamrana I was indeed a dumbass as I forgot to add the UI argument in the creation of the 2 Joueur instances. Thank you and sorry for being such a dumbass...

Comment: Note to all future readers of this page: Please include all relevant information when you yourself are asking a question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jacques Gaudin noticed, you need to change this :

```
class ZombristHash(Hash):
    def __init__(self):
        Hash.__init__()
```

to this :

```
class ZombristHash(Hash):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

and same for UI.

Finally, you get something like this :

```
class Plateau:
    def __init__(self, j1, j2, UI, Hash):
        self.UI = UI
        self.UI.ajoutePlateau(self)
        self.Hash = Hash

class Hash:
    def __init__(self): 
        pass

class ZombristHash(Hash):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

class UI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Plateau = None

    def ajoutePlateau(self, Plateau):
        self.Plateau = Plateau

class UITerminal(UI):
    def __init__(self):
        # super(UITerminal, self).__init__()
        super().__init__()

class Humain():
    def __init__(self, j):
        pass

p = Plateau(Humain("j1"), Humain("j2"), UITerminal(), ZombristHash())
```

Comment: sorry but it does not seems to be the solution, as I had already tried that and still got the exact same error.

Comment: This structure does not give me any error, so you could start from this structure, and then add your code step by step, and see when you get an error. I can't do much for you if you don't give us the full traceback. We don't even know in which class the `TypeError` happens

Comment: That is actually the full traceback... I will do as you say and update the post if I find the source of the problem.